# BIND9 private DNS server with OpenVPN config file errors

Tags: openvpn, bind, ubuntu-14.04

I am setting up a private DNS server that will only be accessible by my OpenVPN users. OpenVPN is setup on the tun0 interface of my Ubuntu 14 server.

The issue is that I am getting some errors. I am unsure how to resolve them. Also I am unsure if if configured my BIND9 server correctly.

Here is what I get when I test my configs:

**named-checkconf:**

> Nothing...

**named-checkzone one.example.com db.one.example.com:**

> db.one.example.com:17: ignoring out-of-zone data
>   (jeannicolas.com.air.jn) zone one.example.com/IN: loaded serial 3 OK

**named-checkzone 8.10.in-addr.arpa /etc/bind/zones/db.10.8:**

> dns_rdata_fromtext: /etc/bind/zones/db.10.8:6: near eol: unexpected end of input 
>   zone 8.10.in-addr.arpa/IN: loading from master file /etc/bind/zones/db.10.8 failed: unexpected end of input 
>   zone 8.10.in-addr.arpa/IN: not loaded due to errors.

**ifconfig details for OpenVPN:**

> tun0
>             Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
>             inet addr:10.8.0.1  P-t-P:10.8.0.2  Mask:255.255.255.255
>             UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>             RX packets:3646 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>             TX packets:3957 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>             collisions:0 txqueuelen:100 
>             RX bytes:476530 (476.5 KB)  TX bytes:2238555 (2.2 MB)

**named.conf.local**

```
zone "one.example.com" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/zones/db.one.example.com"; # zone file path
#       allow-transfer { 10.128.20.12; };         # ns2 private IP address - secondary
};

zone "8.10.in-addr.arpa" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/zones/db.10.8";  # 10.8.0/24 subnet
#       allow-transfer { 10.128.20.12; };  # ns2 private IP address - secondary
};

zone "jn." {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/db.jn";
};
```

**named.conf.options**

```
acl "trusted" {
#       127.0.0.1;
        10.8.0/24;
#       10.8.1.0/24;
};

options {
        directory "/var/cache/bind";

        recursion yes;                 # enables resursive queries
        allow-recursion { trusted; };  # allows recursive queries from "trusted" clients
#       listen-on { 127.0.0.1; };   # ns1 private IP address - listen on private network only
        listen-on { 10.8.0/24 };
        allow-transfer { none; };      # disable zone transfers by default

        forwarders {
                8.8.8.8;
                8.8.4.4;
        };
};
```

**db.10.8**

```
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     one.example.com.        admin.one.example.com. (
                                3       ; Serial
                           604800       ; Refresh
                          2419200       ; Retry
                           604800 )     ; Negative Cache TTL
; name servers
        IN      NS      ns1.one.example.com.

; PTR Records
3.0     IN      PTR     ns1.one.example.com.    ; 10.8.0.3
```

**db.one.example.com**

```
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     ns1.one.example.com. admin.one.example.com. (
                                3       ; Serial
                           604800       ; Refresh
                            86400       ; Retry
                          2419200       ; Expire
                           604800       ; Negative Cache TTL
)
;
; name servers - NS records
        IN      NS      ns1.one.example.com.

; name servers - A records
ns1.one.example.com.            IN      A       10.8.0.3

; 10.8.0.0/16 - A records
jeannicolas.com.air.jn.         IN      A       10.8.0.100
```

**db.jn**

```
;
; BIND data file for TLD ".jn"
;
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     jn.     root.jn. (
                          3             ; Serial
                     604800             ; Refresh
                      86400             ; Retry
                    2419200             ; Expire
                     604800 )           ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@       IN      NS      ns1.jn.
@       IN      A       10.8.0.100
```

Comment: Whats the question? The error you've provided is quite clear: The mentioned zone file isn't valid. Either correct it or remove it, if you don't need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was simple. I did not add a Expire number db.10.8 zone file.

Comment: do you always need the reverse zone?